# An integral involving in Bessel, exponential and power functions

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, bessel-functions

I need to solve an integral similar to the one in a book,  [Abramowitz and Stegun. Handbook of Mathematical Functions,P486, Eq. 11.4.29](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/frameindex.htm). However, I can't use infinity as the upper bound. Can someone give me some clues? Thanks in advance.
The integral would be:

$$ \int_0^{d}e^{-a^2t^2} t^{v+1} J_v(bt)dt$$ or $$ \int_0^{d}e^{-a^2t^2} t J_0(bt)dt$$

Comment: If the upper limit is not infinity, then the integral does not possess a closed form when $d>0$ has a closed form, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$ J_0(t) = \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!^2}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^{2m} \tag{1}$$
and 
$$ b^{2m}\int_{0}^{d}t^{2m+1}e^{-a^2 t^2}\,dt =\frac{b^{2m}}{2 a^{2m+2}}\left(m!-\Gamma(m+1,a^2 d^2)\right)\tag{2}$$
we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{d}e^{-a^2 t^2}t\,J_0(bt)\,dt &=& \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{4^m m!}\cdot\frac{b^{2m}}{2a^{2m+2}}-\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{4^m m!^2}\cdot\frac{b^{2m}}{a^{2m+2}}\Gamma(m+1,a^2 d^2)\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{1}{2a^2}e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}}}-\color{blue}{\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{4^m m!^2}\cdot\frac{b^{2m}}{a^{2m+2}}\Gamma(m+1,a^2 d^2)}\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
an expression (obviously) depending on the [incomplete $\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Comment: OK, thanks everyone. I wonder why the book has only definite integration from zero to infinity. I'll use numerical integration then.